Input Subject is empty in child component Angular 17
I am trying to pass data from a parent to its child component in Angular 17.
The data is retrieved from the back-end through an API that gets an array of items.
In my parent component, items$ is a subject:
items$ = Subject<Array<Item>> = new Subject();

I subscribe it to the method of my service that retrieves all items from the backend:
ngOnInit(){
    this.itemService.getItems().subscribe(this.items$);
}

In my parent.html template, this code does display that there are items:
@if(items$ | async){
"There are items!"
}@else{
"There aren't any items"
}

So I then call my child component:
@if(items$ | async){
<app-child [items$]=items$>
}

This is what my child.component.ts looks like:
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit{
@Input() items$: Observable<Array<Item>>;

ngOnInit(){
this.items$.subscribe();
}
}

An child.component.html:
@if(items$ | async){
"There are items in the child component!"
}@else{
"There aren't any items in the child component"
}

Well, it displays that there aren't any items in the child component.
I know I don't need to subscribe in the onInit() method of my child component, but I really just wanted to make sure that I am indeed subscribed to my multicast observable.
Also, interestingly, when I take my child component out of the @if condition in parent.html, the items are displaying!
Any idea why? And how can I condition the display of my child component to the presence of items?

this.itemService.getItems().subscribe(this.items$) this piece of code looks really strange, what are you trying to achieve with this?

I think I now understand this pattern. When using .subscribe(), instead of a callback function, you can also pass an Observer object instead which has optional properties for next, error and complete. So when passing a Subject, it will call the next function of that subject. Never seen this, but pretty neat.

This is it @JSONDerulo, and I had indeed forgotten to call next() on my subject. It works now :)

You can convert the Subject to a BehaviorSubject, so that it maintains state (the array). Prefer subject when you want to trigger emissions for events (Event Bus) not holding state.
Also you should write a callback inside the subscribe that calls the next method of the BehaviorSubject with the data from the API.
itemService = inject(ItemService);
items$: BehaviorSubject<Array<any> | null> =
  new BehaviorSubject<Array<any> | null>(null);

ngOnInit() {
  this.itemService.getItems().subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.items$.next(data);
  });
}

Full Code:
import { Component, inject, Injectable, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Observable, of, Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ItemService {
  getItems() {
    return of([{ test: 1 }]);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    @if(items$ | async) {
      "There are items in the child component!"
    } @else {
      "There aren't any items in the child component"
    }
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() items$!: Observable<Array<any> | null>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items$.subscribe();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [CommonModule, ChildComponent],
  template: `
    @if(items$ | async){
      "There are items!"
    }@else{
      "There aren't any items"
    }
    <hr/>
    @if(items$ | async) {
      <app-child [items$]="items$"/>
    }
  `,
})
export class App {
  itemService = inject(ItemService);
  items$: BehaviorSubject<Array<any> | null> =
    new BehaviorSubject<Array<any> | null>(null);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.itemService.getItems().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.items$.next(data);
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

That solved it! Thank you so much!

That being said, I don't understand why my iems would be showing in the parent component? I take that they weren't showing in the child because my Subject had not been populated with any data, am I correct?

@Ems I just pasted in both, you can modify it to suit your needs, it has no significance
